# What's the purpose of DISTINCT keyword in Oracle MIN() and MAX() group functions?

Tags: oracle, distinct

I've just found out the DISTINCT keyword is allowed in MIN() and MAX() functions, but I don't get the use of it.

Wouldn't a call to one of the aforementioned functions return the same result either with or without the DISTINCT keyword?

```
SELECT MAX(salary), MAX(DISTINCT salary) from EMPLOYEES;
```

I mean, I get the difference on using the DISTINCT keyword on COUNT(), SUM() or AVG() but I think is useless in both MIN() and MAX()

Comment: Yeap it's useless but still no need to lock functionality of keyword.

Comment: Isn't is possible that this option is common to all aggregate/analytic functions? Maybe it is SQL parser feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `DISTINCT` in `MAX()` and `MIN()` is useless. In `COUNT()`, `SUM()` or `AVG()` result from all values is differs from the result only of unique values. For example, -

```
with t as
(
    select 1 as val from dual union all
    select 1 as val from dual union all
    select 1 as val from dual union all
    select 2 as val from dual union all
    select 3 as val from dual
)
select 
    COUNT(val),             -- =5 (5 rows was selected)
    COUNT(distinct val),    -- =3 (3 rows with unicue value) 
    SUM(val),               -- =8 (1+1+1+2+3)
    SUM(distinct val),      -- =6 (1+2+3, only unique values)
    AVG(val),               -- =1,6 (sum()/count() = 8/5)
    AVG(distinct val)       -- =2 (sum(distinct)/count(distinct) = 6/3)
from t
```

`Max(val)` answers the question - "what is the maximum value in this list [1,1,1,2,3]?" So, `Max(distinct val)` should look for max value in [1,2,3] values list. Its obvious that the results will be equal.